# Unable to Start Activity, Activity can't be Null, but Activity is in Manifest?

Tags: android, android-activity, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception

In the Google Play crash reporter, I'm getting a few unexpected crash reports, and was wondering if some light could be shed as to the cause.

The crash report is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.hvs.tt/com.prime31.FacebookProxyActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: activity cannot be null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
```

In my manifest, I do have that activity declared inside my "application" section:

```
<activity android:name="com.prime31.FacebookProxyActivity"></activity>
```

And my application bundle ID is com.hvs.tt as well. Compounding confusion is that this does seem to work on all of my test devices, but it shows up organically on the app store from time to time.  Is this something I can fix, or is it an issue with a specific users device???

Comment: This issue is not related to the manifest. When you forget to add an activity to the manifest, you don't get this exception; you get an exception with a message that explicitly tells you you are missing the activity in the manifest. If you cannot reproduce, then chances are that this is device specific.

Comment: Is there a common link in the Android versions?  I can't remember the details now but there were problems pre-Gingerbread where using dotted notation worked, i.e. `<activity android:name=".FacebookProxyActivity"></activity>`

Comment: So far, I've seen the issue on "Galaxy S3" and "HTC One V", with Android OS 4.0.3 & 4.3.

Looking back at previous versions, it seems to mostly occur on Android 4.x; kind of surprising since they are newer Android versions.